# How to $push: into mongo-db after incrementing id using $inc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to to increment the value of the ID before inserting into the Mongodb. I tried $inc but it ain't working .
Here is my Mongoose Schema

```
const subSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type:Number,
        default:1

    },
    time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})
const activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    activity:[subSchema]
})
```

**I am trying to update id in subSchema which is later used in activitySchema**

This is what id did initially.

`findOneAndUpdate({userid:userid}, { $push: { activity: {description:"Test",$inc:{ id: 1} } } })`

**Document is getting inserted but with default value as 1 for all**
When i removed default:1 from id, The document is getting updated without id
Any easy solution for this ?

Comment: means you want to push data inside `subschema` and simultaneously increment its `id` value. like before: `{userid: 'A', activity:[ { id:1, time: '2021-...', description: 'lorem ipsum' } ]}` and after: `{userid: 'A', activity:[ { id:1, time: '2021-...', description: 'lorem ipsum' }, { id:2, time: '2021-...', description: 'lorem ipsum' } ]}` ... Am I right???

Comment: @TalESid Yes , Exactly

Comment: No easy way to do this I'm afraid. Mongo wasn't built for that. Also, sequential IDs are usually a bad idea. Why not use uuids ?

Comment: @RaniSharim I could use UUIDs but the front-end team is not that comfortable with UUIDs . So I thought making it as sequential id's will do better

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to be done in one query. Instead you can do it in 2 steps as:

```
const user = await Activity.findOne({ userid });
//                  ^^^^^ put your collection name here
if (user) {
    const activityCount = user.activity.length;

    await user.updateOne({ $push: { activity:
        { id: activityCount + 1, description: 'Dolor sit amet' }
    }})
}
```

Comment: I already did something similar by taking the id of the last inserted element and incrementing it by one. But I was wondering why my code(the one I mentioned in the question) is not working. I Appreciate if you can explain that too .